# Can Lock_timeout be set as same value STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can Lock_timeout be set as 3 times less than STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS in snowflake so that it waits to get a lock on the resource if not will abort the queued query?

I have a case where concurrently delete query has taken long time in "waiting for locks" phase since the query/job needs to wait for table resource because it is locked by the other transaction.

Answer (score 0):

LOCK_TIMEOUT can be set at the account, session or user level.  It can be set to the same value that you set STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS or any value.

Comment: Documentation here as well on this parameter: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#lock-timeout